# .Kar file on IOS xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, visualizer, temenos-quantum

If i have .Kar file generated from kony visualizer provided to me how can I run it on Xcode and on IOS emulator

I tried to run this command **perl extract.pl konyappiphone.KAR** on gen folder inside visualizer's installation folder and drag and drop kar file but it seems like the xCode runs only the app that was built already on visualizer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.